# how to draw polygon cross the day line in Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to draw a polygon cross the day line on Google map, but it only gives me the part on one side of the day line i.e a smaller shade part as the picture shows:
[image]

Here are my coordinates:

North Latitude: 71.2683°

East Longitude: 145.7786°

South Latitude: -14.3576°

West Longitude: -178.8774°

Here is the code I have:

```
var north = 71.2683;
var south = -14.3576;
var east = 145.7786;
var west = -178.8774;

var rectCoords = [
    {lat: north, lng: west},
    {lat: north, lng: east},
    {lat: south, lng: east},
    {lat: south, lng: west}
];

var rect = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [rectCoords],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.35,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0,
    clickable: false
});

rect.setMap(maps["my_map"]);
```

I know it might be solve by using the Rectangle API in Google Map, but for my project purpose, I need to use Polygon API. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add points along the top and bottom edges in the middle of the path:

```
var rectCoords = [
    {lat: north, lng: west},
    {lat: north, lng: (west+east)/2},
    {lat: north, lng: east},
    {lat: south, lng: east},
    {lat: south, lng: (west+east)/2},
    {lat: south, lng: west}
];
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8kpeb62L/)

[image: screen shot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var north = 71.2683;
  var south = -14.3576;
  var east = 145.7786;
  var west = -178.8774;

  var rectCoords = [{
      lat: north,
      lng: west
    },
    {
      lat: north,
      lng: (west + east) / 2
    },
    {
      lat: north,
      lng: east
    },
    {
      lat: south,
      lng: east
    },
    {
      lat: south,
      lng: (west + east) / 2
    },
    {
      lat: south,
      lng: west
    }
  ];

  var rect = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [rectCoords],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.35,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0,
    clickable: false
  });

  rect.setMap(map);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < rectCoords.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(rectCoords[i]);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```